# With Ember and Ember-data: How to setup callback when a store is finished loading, and/or when an associated view is finished re-rendering?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember and Ember-data to load a few hundred objects from a REST API, using a findAll call within a custom adapter.  I have an ArrayController.content referencing the findAll, and then use the [recently added Ember.Select](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/424/files) to display the objects in a select widget/dropdown-menu.  I need to run a function on the select widget once it is fully rendered with all the objects (each object being an option of the select) - in particular, the [Chosen.js library](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/).

Because it takes a little while (2-4 seconds) to handle the few hundred objects in the select, using callbacks on the events Ember.Select.didInsertElement and Ember.ArrayController.contentDidChange don't quite work; they both fire too soon.  So is there another event, or another approach, which could be used instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DS.RESTAdapter.findQuery` is the answer! In contrast to the `DS.RESTAdapter.findAll` method, it creates and returns `DS.AdapterPopulatedModelArray`, which has it's own *isLoaded* properly that you can observe anywhere in your app!

For example:

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});

App.set('MyItemList', App.store.findQuery(App.Item, 'homepageList'));

App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    refresh: function () {
        console.log('finished loading custom list');
    }.observes('App.MyItemList.isLoaded')
});
```